# Sorting files into folders by file name using .bat

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, aggregation

Consider a parent folder
C:\Users..\Parent
Under parent there are 3 folders M1,M2,M3
C:\Users..\Parent\M1, C:\Users..\Parent\M2, C:\Users..\Parent\M3.
Under M1,M2,M3 there is 100 sub folders.
C:\Users..\Parent\M1\MattP001M1,C:\Users..\Parent\M1\MattP002M1,so on till C:\Users..\Parent\M1\MattP100M1. Similarly for M2,M3 as well.

---

Under every folder(MattP001M1..MattP100M1) there are a ton of .wav files(close to 1500 on an avg).
These wav files have a pattern in their naming.
e.g: There are 20 files with German_09mea4567_morename and 15 files with German_4132azzi_morename and so on.
I am using this script on them to group them in folders based on the unique part after(09mea4567).

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in (*.wav) do (
set f=%%a
set g=!f:~7,8!
md "!g!" 2>nul
move "%%a" "!g!"
)
```

---

Now this is fine for one folder. I want to do this for all the folders under M1(MattP001M1,..,MattP100M1), M2, M3.

Please note: This is a setup on one machine. On a different machine instead of German there is some other language.

Hope i made myself much clearer this time

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong or i don't understand the question, but it seems repeating the same code for each of the subfolders doesn't make sense. Assuming there is a folder "01", all the files in it where placed because their 7th and 8th characters are equal. Running the same code again against these files will only generate another "01" folder under "01" folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting files into folders based on a pattern in their name using .bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656263/sorting-files-into-folders-based-on-a-pattern-in-their-name-using-bat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Solved my problem. Thanks to [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656263/sorting-files-into-folders-based-on-a-pattern-in-their-name-using-bat/20657525?noredirect=1#20657525) by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)

```
@echo off

rem Prepare environment
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem configure where to start
set "root=c:\somewhere"

rem For each file under root that match indicated pattern
for /r "%root%" %%f in (*_*_*.wav) do (

    rem Split the file name in tokens using the underscore as delimiter
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%p in ("%%~nf") do (

        rem Test if the file is in the correct place
        for %%d in ("%%~dpf.") do if /i not "%%~p"=="%%~nd" (

            rem if it is not, move it where it should be
            if not exist "%%~dpf\%%~p"  md "%%~dpf\%%~p"
            move "%%~ff" "%%~dpf\%%~p"
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /d %%x in ("x:\parent folder\folder*") do (
    pushd "%%~x"
    for %%a in (*.wav) do for /f "tokens=1-4delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
        md "%%~e" 2>nul
        move "*_*_*_%%~e%%~xa" "%%~e" 2>nul
    )
    popd
)
```

Comment: @Matt I made some enhancements.

Comment: Can u kindly explain what your code is doing? Helps me understand better